# Wagtail API - how to expose snippets

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, wagtail

Imagine I have a `Snippet` and a `Page` containing it:

```
@register_snippet
class MySnippet(models.Model):
    content = models.CharField(max_length=255)


class MyPage(Page):
    snippet = models.ForeignKey('MySnippet', null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name='+')

    api_fields = [
        APIFiled('snippet')
    ]
```

Now in the wagtail API page endpoint this page will look like this:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "meta": { ... },
    "snippet": {
        "id": 1,
        "meta": {
            "type": "my_module.MySnippet"
        }
    }
}
```

What can I do to make this endpoint displaying snippet's content?

Also, how do I create a separate API endpoint only for snippets?

Answer (score 6):

I'm not sure how to answer the main question, but I can help with creating separate API endpoints for snippets.

You have to create an endpoints.py file in your app root, using the existing Wagtail endpoint classes as a base, such as `BaseAPIEndpoint`

Then, register the new endpoint in your api.py file.

endpoints.py

```
from wagtail.api.v2.endpoints import BaseAPIEndpoint
from .models import MySnippetModel

class MySnippetModelAPIEndpoint(BaseAPIEndpoint):

    model = MySnippetModel

    body_fields = BaseAPIEndpoint.body_fields + [
        'field_1',
        'field_2',
        'field_3',
    ]

    listing_default_fields = BaseAPIEndpoint.listing_default_fields = [
        'field_1',
        'field_2',
        'field_3',
    ]
```

api.py

```
from .endpoints import MySnippetModelAPIEndpoint

...

sua_api_router.register_endpoint('snippets', MySnippetModelAPIEndpoint)
```

I would also look at the endpoints.py file in Wagtail core, so you can see what else you can extend or modify.

https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/blob/master/wagtail/api/v2/endpoints.py

Answer (score 5):

Here's how I did it, it was a simple enough representation though in my case

```
from rest_framework import serializers

class MyPage(Page):
    snippet = models.ForeignKey('MySnippet', null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name='+')

    api_fields = [
        APIField('snippet', serializer=serializers.StringRelatedField(many=True))
    ]
```

And you can add a '**str**' method to your snippet

```
@register_snippet
class MySnippet(models.Model):
    content = models.CharField(max_length=255)

        def __str__(self):
            return self.content
```

Answer (score 0):

An up to date APIViewSet (which older Wagtail versions would refer to as an APIEndpoint) would be:

```py
class MyAPIViewSet(BaseAPIViewSet):
    # BaseSerializer is enough for simple fields.
    base_serializer_class = BaseSerializer
    body_fields = BaseAPIViewSet.body_fields + ["field1", "field2"]
    meta_fields = BaseAPIViewSet.meta_fields + ["field1"]
    listing_default_fields = BaseAPIViewSet.listing_default_fields + ["field1", "field2"]
    nested_default_fields = BaseAPIViewSet.nested_default_fields + ["field1"]
    name = "mymodels"
    model = MyModel
```

Then in `api.py`:

```py
api_router.register_endpoint("mymodels", MySnippetModelAPIEndpoint)
```

You have to create one such ViewSet for each Snippet you want to expose through the API.